# Adding one repo's history to another

Tags: git, github

I have two repos:

**Repo 1**
A template repo that receives generic codebase updates and improvements.

**Repo 2**
Cloned from Repo 1 but published without Repo 1's history. Contains most if not all files from Repo 1 + more.

I'd like to keep developing both of these repos independently, but still be able to merge any generic fixes added to Repo 1 into Repo 2.

This can be done by using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag when merging, but it's still quite prone to error and ideally I'd like not to have to troubleshoot merge conflicts every time I want to merge Repo 1 into Repo 2.

Is there any way to achieve this? I don't mind losing history from Repo 2 as long as all the files stay intact.

Comment: The idea seems wrong. How would you prevent (or handle) changing files owned by Repo 1 in Repo 2?

Comment: I'd still have merge conflicts which I'd need to manually resolve, but I assume they'd be less. With `--allow-unrelated-histories` I get merge conflicts for files that exactly the same.

Comment: You can't merge them like normal but git has the option to generate patch files from commits or branches and a way to convert patch files back into commits

Comment: @mousetail do you have more info about this?

Comment: Merging, even with `--allow-unrelated-histories` will defiantly not work, cherry picking might

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick